# Negative number to a string. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert a negative int to individual digit in an array? Something like this...

```
x = -3987
arr = [-3,9,8,7]
```

I tried to do this but I got an error.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

```
x = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
```

Comment: The only time you will have a negative number is for the left most digit, I would handle that case seperately and simply change your list comprehension to 
arr = [int(i) for i in str(x)[1:]
Then you can have a conditional which checks the original number and changes the arr[0] if its negative.

Comment: Remark above is correct, but has a typo, you should use `arr = [int(i) for i in str(x)[1:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I will handle it. The answer was already provided by @Fuledbyramen.

```
x = -3987
#arr = [-3,9,8,7]

if x < 0:
     arr = [int(i) for i in str(x)[1:]]
     arr[0] *= -1
else:
    arr = [int(i) for i in str(x)]

print (arr)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[-3,9,8,7]
```

If value of x was 3987

```
x = 3987
```

then the output will be:

```
[3,9,8,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension works here

```
x = -3987
xs = str(x)

lst = [int(d) for d in (([xs[:2]]+list(xs[2:])) if xs[0]=='-' else xs)]

print(lst)
```

Output

```
[-3, 9, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
input_number = +223
res_digits = list(str(input_number))

if res_digits[0] == '-':
    res_digits[0] = res_digits[0] + res_digits[1]
    res_digits.pop(1)
elif res_digits[0] == '+':
    res_digits.pop(0)

print(list(map(int, res_digits)))
```